# Requesting information about expression $(1-t)a+tb$

Tags: functions

I noticed that the expression $(1-t)a+tb$ is used often in proofs. Is it a well-known expression? If so, why is it used in so many proofs (such as Brouwer’s fixed point theorem) and definitions (such as the convex sets definition). I would appreciate if you can provide me with additional information about it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Weighted average of $a$ and $b$. As $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$, the expression varies linearly from $a$ to $b$

Comment: If $t$ is restricted to be between 0,1 inclusive, then it is simply the line connecting a to b.

Comment: Actually if $t\in [0,1]$ you get the line segment from a to b.  If you don't restrict $t$ you get the whole line